# "Lazy initialization" of jdbc connections from jndi datasource/connection pool: feasibility

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, jndi, connection-pooling

I have a main controller servlet in which i instantiate a **datasource**. The servlet opens and closes the connections. Mainly, the servlet instantiates a command from the application using the "factory pattern". here is some code to explain:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    try {
            datasource =(DataSource) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBCPool");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
  //some code...
  Connection connection = null;
  if(cmd.mightNeedLazyLoadingAConnection)
  {

       connection = null;
  } 
  else 
       connection = getConnection();//where getConnection is a method: datasource.getconnection();

      //now a command (a java class) is instantied, to which the "null" CONNECTION obj is passed as parameter
     cmdFactory.getInstance().getCommand(Cmd).execute(tsk,connection);


  //some code

//Then wherever there is catch exception i close() the connection
// and it is always closed in finally
finally { 
 if(connection!=null)
  connection.close()
 }

}
```

Now , this has a **problem** for the first case, ie **connection=null**, as it does never close the connection in the **"finally"** part (explained why in **Update** below).

**"connection=null"** is for cases where commands might not need to open a db connection because the data it is seeking for are cached in an [identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html).

I tried to pass the  **"Connection"** obj as a "null" parameter in the **.execute(tsk,connection);** and then in the corresponding java class to open a connection **if** needed

--> it did open the connection inside the command, however when process goes back to servlet : **"Connection" is null as thus not closed.** 
What can i do to make the **"Connection"** obj's value get updated so that when back in servlet it is not "Null" anymore and i'd be able to close it?

I generally prefer to use a controller servlet that **opens/close** db connections, so what would be the best way to deal this kind of scenario where you have to do some sort of "lazy loading" a db connection from the pool and at the same time keep the **opens/close** of db connection assigned to the servlet?

**Update (to explain further):**

- say i have a command : **X.java**
- this command might/might not need a db connection (depends if the data searched for are in the identity map or not)

The system that i would like to have is:

(1)**"client request"**

(2)---> **"Servlet":** command.execute(connection)//where connection = null for now

(3) ---> **"Command X"**: Do i need to go to database or record is in identity map?
(3.a) Case where it is needed to go to the database: 
(3.a.1)connection = datasource.getconnection
(3.a.2) go get the data

(4)--->**back** to servlet: **close "connection" in "Servlet"**

Right now it is working until (3.a.2), but once back in (4) it appears that connection is still "null" and thus the code:

```
finally { 
 if(connection!=null)
  connection.close()
 }
```

Does **not work (doesn't close the connection)** and thus the db pool get drained like that.
How could connection - which starts as "null" and changes inside command "X"- get "globaly" updated to the its new value, and not only "updated" inside the scope of command "X"?

**SOLUTION(S)**

In case you are encountering the same scenario, you can chose of these **2 solutions:**

- You can Either use [LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html), as mentionned by @Ryan Stewart for a "clean abstraction" and more professional solution
- Or if you'd like use my solution described below (Basically i implemented a class similar to "LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy" but it is not as clean, it has less abstraction of details than "LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy")

**My personal solution, Details:**

- I created a "Helper" class, which constructor takes the "datasource" as parameter
- This helper class has methods to: "Lazy get" connection from pool,"close" connection
- This class is instantiated in the servlet, and it gets a connection from the pool **Only** if needed throughout the application.

This is the code i added/modified in the servlet:

```
Connection connection = null;
if(cmd.mightNeedLazyLoadingAConnection)
{

     helper hp =  new helper(datasource);
     cmdFactory.getInstance().getCommand(Cmd).execute(tsk,hp);
} 
else 
{
     connection = getConnection(); 
     cmdFactory.getInstance().getCommand(Cmd).execute(tsk,connection);
}
```

Then say in a command "X" , a db connection is needed i do:

```
Connection connection = hp.LazyGet();//Now got a connection from the pool
```

And this way, when proccess flow is back to the servlet level, i can :

- Close
- rollback
- commit
- etc..

All on this hp object of the helper class.

**What benefits do i get from this:**

- I limit all database *open / close / commit / rollback* in **one** place, ie the Servlet, which is responsible of executing commands.
- Having **3** cases: *never needs db / always needs db / might need db* thus now i decreased calls to the database by **1/3** , which is quite a lot knowing that database call grows exponentially with new features and new users registrations.

It might not be the **Cleanest**  workaround, but between this way and having an additional "unnecessary" 1/3 database calls, it surely is better. Or just use [LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html) if you want a *Tested, abstract and clean method.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html). Then just get a "connection" every time, but a real connection is opened only when you actually do something that requires one. Thus you obey the "create/destroy" wisdom which Hiro2k pointed out because the connection's lifecycle is completely managed by your servlet.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I just posted my solution few min ago. I am not using frameworks, but i did some sort of helper/proxy class (check my answer).

Comment: I didn't say anything about using a framework. The `LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy` does almost the same thing that your solution describes, except that it hides the dirty details behind a clean abstraction layer. There's no concept of "might need a connection" or "lazy get". You just treat it like a normal `DataSource` that provides normal `Connection`s, and you get the laziness for free. It's a considerably better option for those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case the only way to do it would be to return the connection. Java doesn't have any pass by reference semantics that could help you, unlike C where you could pass in the reference to the connection and then set it within the method.

I don't recommend your method return the connection, instead remember this simple rule and everything will work as you expect:

> The object that creates it, is responsible for destroying it.

If what you want to do is not instantiate a connection for commands that don't require one, then add a method to your command interface that simply returns if needs one.

```
Command command = cmdFactory.getInstance().getCommand(Cmd);
if(command.requiresConnections){
     connection = getConnection();
}
command.execute(tsk,connection);
```

Comment: thx for the tips. I cannot return the connection since each command return data to send to the client side. As for:"The object that creates it, is responsible for destroying it." , very true but that will mean i will have to open/close the connection in each command. I am trying to see if there would probably be a way to leave the open/close only in one place, ie the servlet. If it appears that there is absolutely no way, then i'll follow what you said.

Comment: thanks again, but I think you misunderstood my question, what you wrote is what i already have in my code. The code as it is now "Always" opens a connection, and what i want to know is when a command might/might not need a connection, how do you pass a "connection" null object to the command, and "There" you open a connection, and when the flow goes back to servlet you "close" that "connection" in the servlet.

Comment: On what criteria you decide "when a command might/might not need a connection"

Comment: @HardikMishra I have a filter for that check from a dictionary if a command requires/might require(lazy loading)/doesn't require connections

Comment: You didn't understand my code shadesco. What I'm proposing is that you create a new method called requiresConnections uses that same logic to tell the servlet that it needs to create the connection. I've already said that it's impossible to do it the way you want, but this alternative should still solve your problem.